# Find string in line, then append it to same line

Tags: bash, sed

In my bash script, I want to search the file `/etc/hosts` for a substring `olr4.dtf21`, split that into two variables, then append them to the same line.

Here is the line in the file:

```
137.222.209.123 olr4.dtf21.fltops.cat.dog.com olr4
```

What I want to do is make the line end up like:

```
137.222.209.123 olr4.dtf21.fltops.cat.dog.com olr4 olr4.dtf21
```

I figure I can use sed to do this, but getting a substring out and into variables is above me for the time being.

Comment: Is it always this exact substring? If not, how is it defined what you want to capture and append?

Comment: It also looks like you didn't really split into two variables, you just appended the exact same string.

Comment: If you can accomplish your task with sed, as you say , what is the purpose of "getting a substring out and into variables"?  Why do you want it in "variables"?

Comment: Benjamin, No, olr4.dtf21 can be something like olr2.gdsss.

Comment: Benjamin: I would like olr4 in one variable, and dtf21 in another. I need to use these elsewhere in the script.

Answer (score 0):

You requirement is not clear.  If you are looking for a pattern that has two parts, you could do this in `awk`:

```
awk -v var1="value1" -v var2="value2" '
    $2 ~ var1"."var2 { print $0" "var1"."var2; next } # matching lines
                     { print                        } # other lines
    ' /etc/hosts
```